# Cyclic relationship between an interface and a generic class constraint

Tags: c#, generics, interface, constraints

I seem to be in a thought loop about this. I can't use references to the parent NameManager in INameManageable (objects of which are owned by NameManager) because it is generic.

On the other hand if I make INameManageable itself a generic interface (i.e. INameManageable < T >), I could use references to NameManager < T > inside of it. But then I am not able to derive all my nameable classes from one and the same INameManageable anymore.

```
public interface INameManageable
{
    NameManager getParent(); // doesn't work because NameManager is generic!
    setParent(NameManager newParent);
    string getName(); // not relevant for the problem
    void setName(string name);
}

public class NameManager<T> where T: INameManageable
{
    readonly List<T> namedItems = new List<T>();

    public T Add(T item)
    {
        item.setParent(this);
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}

public class X: INameManageable
{
    // ...
}

public class Y: INameManageable
{
    // ...
}

public class ABunchOfNameManagers
{
    NameManager<X> anXNameManager;
    NameManager<Y> aYNameManager;
}
```

How can I establish a reference to the parent in this scenario? I am probably going to facepalm myself, once I know how...

Comment: Can you not just make both the interface and the interface generic?

Comment: @JD Davis: but wouldn't X have to be derived from INameManageable<X> and Y derived from INameManageable<Y> then? I am clueless...

Comment: Or rather in your interface, why not make the return type and parameter type `INameManageable` rather than `NameManager`. That one change should correct the issue.

Comment: @JDDavis: because INameManageable is something completely different than NameManager. INameManageable are the Items, NameManager is the container.

Comment: What's the point of `INameManageable` to have a `NameManager getParent();`? That seems like a very bad design.

Comment: You are implementing the interface so why not do this: `INameManageable getParent();`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Sometimes children know their parents, be it bad design or not. In this case the children need to inform the parent about somebody trying to rename them without proper name control.

Comment: @CodingYoshi: INameManageable is the child, NameManager is the parent container, so why should I return a INameManageable with getParent?

Comment: @oliver because `NameManager<T>` implements the `INameManageable` interface so you will get what you want. Why do you want a concrete type?

Comment: @CodingYoshi: No, NameManager<T> does not implement INameManageable, but it constrains T to being INameManageable! That's the job of the where keyword as far as I know.

Comment: @oliver crap my bad...yes you are right.

Comment: @oliver If the manageable object needs to have a way of informing any users of them that an invalid change has been made than it should define an event.  The manager can subscribe to that event and do what it needs to do when that situation comes up.  That's how you ensure that the managed object doesn't know about the object that manages it.

Comment: @CodingYoshi: no problem. It is easy to miss the where. :-)

Comment: @oliver this can work too: `NameManager<INameManageable> getParent();` but during setting you would need to do this: `item.setParent(this as NameManager<INameManageable>);`

Comment: @CodingYoshi That cast would always fail, as the NameManger's generic argument isn't going to be `INameManageable`, it's going to be some derived type.

Comment: @Servy: that's definitely a good idea. If there's no solution to my question then I'll go for an event. But for now my mind is already messed by the original problem (referring to the parent directly), I would at least like to know how one could make it work.

Comment: @Servy again, yes you are right. Not my day...going home.

Comment: I was going to answer this following @Servy's approach, then I realized that would be the same as implementing [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now I got it! It is basically what @JDDavis has suggested in his (deleted) answer. Thanks, man, I wish I could upvote you again for that! Sorry for not seeing the potential.

The key is making the interface generic as well.

```
public interface INameManageable<T>
{
    NameManager<T> getParent();
    string getName();

    // derived class should use explicit interface implementation
    // so that no-one from external can fiddle with name or parent
    setParent(NameManager<T> newParent);
    void setName(string name);
}

public class NameManager<T> where T: class, INameManageable<T>
{
    readonly List<T> namedItems = new List<T>();

    public T Add(T item)
    {
        // ...
        namedItems.Add(item);
        item.setParent(this);
    }
}

public class X: INameManageable<X>
{
    // publicly accessible
    public NameManager<T> getParent() {/* ... */}
    public string getName() {/* ... */}

    // this is called "explicit interface implementation";
    // basically means "private", unless somebody explicitly
    // casts us to the interface (so it's at least discouraged)
    void INameManageable<T>.setName(string name) {/* ... */}
    void INameManageable<T>.setParent(NameManager<T> nameManager) {/* ... */}
}

public class Y: INameManageable<Y>
{
    // ... same here ...
}

public class ABunchOfNameManagers
{
    NameManager<X> anXNameManager;
    NameManager<Y> aYNameManager;
}
```

Thanks to you all for the fruitful discussion!

**Edit:** I forgot to sync the changes that I have made in the meantime. I suspect this is what led @Servy to his criticism about type safety. Anyway it is working fine for my application.

Comment: This doesn't have an type safety.  You can have a `NameManager<X>` as the parent of a `Y`, and you can use a `NameManager<Y>` to request a name change of an `X`.  If you're going to do this you might as well just remove all of the generics entirely, remove `INameManager`, and just let a name manager manage any type of manageable name (because that's how it works already).  Or, of course, you could do as was suggested earlier and have the manageable objects not know about the objects that manage them, which removes all of the problems and has the bonus of being a more maintainable design.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, but it requires an explicit cast to the Interface, which is safe enough for me. Also, events are a concept for loose coupling whereas ownership is - by design - tight coupling. Or else how should I know if a INameManageable is already owned by a different NameManager, if not by the parent reference of INameManageable. The "ensure that the managed object doesn't know about the object that manages it" argument does not apply here. It already knows about it. It is probably not a perfect solution, but if there's no better one (excluding events), I will go for this one.

Comment: Any manager can be set as the manager of any manageable object, at any time, with no casting required.  There's simply no checking there.  The managed objects *only* interact with their manager through the interface in your example, so no explicit casting would be required for them to act on a different type of manager because they're *already* only using the interface to interact with them.  Your solution has already removed *all* static typing in the relationship between the manager and the managed object..

Comment: If you want to ensure that a manageable object is only managed by one manager then this isn't accomplishing that (as any manager can still set itself as the manager of a manageable that someone else is already managing).  If you want to ensure that only one manager manages the manageable object then the manager should be creating the manageable object and not exposing it externally, so that no one else could possibly manage it.  That would be proper encapsulation

Comment: Another point that's ugly about the event approach is, that I would have to subscribe to several events individually if there are several messages to be exchanged. There's also nothing in INameManageable implementations that leads the compiler to remind me of the necessity to subscribe. Whereas with the interface approach I have just one compact contract, the compiler will not let me sneak around.

Comment: If you want to do your work with one event, you could.  Without knowing the specifics of what's going on it's to hard to say if multiple events would be beneficial.  As for discoverability, I see no meaningful difference at all being having to just "know" that an object expects you to call `SetParent` on it for it to function Vs needing to subscribe to an event if you want to perform some action when a condition is met.  In both cases you have a member on the object that you call to accomplish the same thing.  (If anything, the event is *more* explicit about what's going on.)

Comment: @Servy: you may be right in specific scenarios. But I am already using it the way I want it to, and it does exactly what I want.